# Magento URL indexer in progress joinLeft slow query in Category/Flat.php causes site outage

Tags: mysql, magento

Software: Magento Community
Flat Category Index enabled

Description of problem:
When I run a full URL index, it takes a very long time to complete, which I understand can be normal in some circumstances. This is not the issue im asking about. While the indexer is running the block cache continuously gets invalidated. When this happens, Magento tries to rebuild the menu from the flat category table while joining the url rewrite table. This is a part of the core in file
**Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php**

While the indexer runs, this query repeatedly shows up in mysql client connections.

```
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, main_table.`name`, main_table.`path`, `main_table`.`is_active`, `main_table`.`is_anchor`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path`, `main_table`.`url_override`, `main_table`.`display_subcategories` 
 FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_19` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND url_rewrite.product_id IS NULL AND url_rewrite.store_id='19' AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%' 
 WHERE (main_table.is_active = '1') AND (main_table.include_in_menu = '1') AND (main_table.path like '1/1877/%') AND (`level` <= 3) 
 ORDER BY `main_table`.`position` ASC
```

This query is extremely slow due to the joinLeft. This Join is defined in the file mentioned above. When the indexer is running, this query times out. Connections build up on the server all trying to run the same query to rebuild the navigation menu.

if I change the query to a joinInner instead of a joinLeft, the problem immediately goes away. I do not understand the purpose of a left join, because I think its highly unlikely there wouldn't be a value in this table, and if there wasn't we might not want to show this category.

I have seen a least a few other reports of this problem, but they are quickly brushed off with a generic performance issue while running index or cache.

I dont understand why this query acts very differently when the indexer runs because I can do a full select on each table individually in a normal amount of time. Only with the left join combined with the indexer does this problem happen. Understand that in general this is a slow query.

Question: Can you please provide information on the left join, why it is needed because its very slow. Can you also recommend a solution to solve my problem.

Comment: There are many things going on here. The indexer will invalidate the cache right away, so all the front-end requests that come in while the nav block is not in the cache will each try to rebuild it (queries ran by the default navigation block in Magento 1.X are expensive). The issue is avoided in Magento 2 and 3rd party extensions by making the navigation HTML generated and cached/stored elsewhere, only being updated when it is regenerated. And in the case of the indexer, invalidated only after the data is updated, not before it runs.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens because it is just a problem query in this version of Magento. Later versions of Community have rewritten this method/query to not have any left join.

There is still an issue where the block cache is invalidated and the menu is getting regenerated, but the main issue reported is solved.

The function in reference is getParentCategories of file Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php